# Create Product at Magento 2.3.3 Using REST in C#

Tags: product, rest-api, create, c#

I'm trying to create simple Product by Rest Api status code is ok

Although I can not see the product in Magento2, Here is my code :

```
Token = this.GetAdminToken("admin", "password");
 var request = CreateRequest("/V1/products", Method.POST, Token);
 var product = new M2Product();
 product.Sku = "BA3245";
 product.Name = "PRoductx";
 product.Price = 100;
 product.Status = 1;
 product.Visibility = 4;
 product.AttributeSetId = 4;
 product.TypeId = "simple";

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
request.AddParameter("application/json", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);
 var response = Client.Execute(request);
if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK){
    }else{
    }
```

I wonder if the installation or configuration of something is missing
Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: use method `PUT` and the  use URL `www.domain.com/rest/V1/products/{SKU}`

Comment: I want to create new product  it give me Unauthorized when I used "rest/V1/products"

Comment: Did you used Header as Authorization: Bearer {{admin token}}?

Comment: private RestRequest CreateRequest(string endPoint, Method method,string token)
        {
            var request = new RestRequest(endPoint, method);
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            return request;
        }
    }

Comment: I used RestRequest method

Comment: I'm not good in c#.... I can give you curl code instead...Is that ok?

Comment: ok I can read curl code may be  .. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Get Admin token using your admin username and password

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -i 'http://www.domain.com/rest/V1/integration/admin/token' --data '{
"username":"USERNAME",
"password":"PASSWORD"
}'
```

You can get your token and use token in below product creation request

```
curl -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Bearer ADMIN_TOKEN' -i 'http://www.domain.com/rest/V1/products/121' --data '{
 "product": {
   "sku": "121",
   "name": "B2021",
   "price": 30.00,
   "status": 1,
   "type_id": "simple",
   "attribute_set_id":4,
   "weight": 1
 }
}'
```

Hope you can convert this curl code into C#

Comment: when endpoint: /rest/V1/products  response result : Unauthorized .endpoint :/api/rest/V1/products  response result : OK but product is not exist magento endpoint:/hhtp://localhost/magento/rest/V1/products result : forbidden

Comment: What is the method you used?

Comment: I'm not understand you .. I use Post method .. am I missing any configuration or installation

Comment: Use `PUT` method for adding product. Magento allows PUT method only to create a product by default

Comment: when I use PUT method it give notfound message

Comment: Did you used `/V1/products/yoursku`?

Comment: now add sku but it give message Unauthorized

Comment: Please check that admin user has product access privilege?

Comment: the user role is Adnministrator how can I see this user has product access privilege excuse me I am new at magento

Comment: `Adnministrator` role will have all the permission. How did you got admin token? Did you used `rest/V1/integration/admin/token`?

Comment: yes this is method:      var request = CreateRequest("/rest/V1/integration/admin/token", Method.POST);

Comment: var user = new Credentials();
            user.username = userName;
            user.password = passWord;

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user, Formatting.Indented);

            request.AddParameter("application/json", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);

            var response = Client.Execute(request);
            if(response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                return response.Content;
            }else
            {
                return "";
            }

Comment: Ok... You got token from this right...Used this token like `Bearer token`?

Comment: yes I use Bearer token

Comment: thank you very much to your effort .. I delete Integrate and new integrate I take new generated consumer Keys .. it is run correctly

Comment: Oh...Sounds great..

Comment: Accept my answer or add your answer for others.

Comment: excuse me  how I accept your answer I don't know

Comment: Click tick icon on left of the answer...

Comment: there is a flag.. when click flag there 3 option harassment,unfriendly vs .. I can't find other icon

Comment: Check here - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: you did not answer button.. your message at  comment . ..the icon exist at answer option Please open Answer and  write message

Comment: I didn't get you..

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100728/discussion-on-answer-by-ranganathan-create-product-at-magento-2-3-3-using-rest-i).